# How do you write non ASCII Unicode Characters using a Java FileWriter?

Tags: java, html, xml, unicode, groovy

I have thousands of HTML files to process using Groovy/Java and I need to produce XML at the end. Some of the files have the character escape sequence `&#8217;` in them. When I produce the output XML the subsequent parse of that XML is complaining about an illegal unicode character in the file. The sequence I am going through is HTML file->HTMLCleaner->SimpleXMLSerializer->XMLSlurper->CLOB (in HSQLDB)->ClobInputStream->FileWriter.

How do I get the correct character code in the output so that the parser doesn't complain?

Note: This question has been heavily modified to correctly represent what the real problem was. The comments below refer to the original version.

Comment: Why does it have to be in Java/Groovy (as opposed to, e.g., some shell/Perl scripts)?

Comment: To add to Emil Sit's comment, this doesn't seem to be a very well defined question.  You should provide an example of the problem, and what your expected outcome is.  Anyone could write you a script to blindly replace all `'` with `"` or whatever, but that might not even be the actual problem, or might create more problems.

Comment: Emil, I could use cygwin to do it but that would mean that users of the code would need to install it.

Comment: OverZealoous, I have clarified the question. I'm happy to write the code if someone can point me in the right direction. To be clear there are thousands of files so performance is an important characteristic.

Comment: @Peter Kelley: one (or several) of your *"several processes"* [sic] is/are broken.  &#8217 is U+2019 and named *RIGHT SINGLE QUOTATION MARK* and shouldn't cause any issue.

Comment: @user988052 you were right on the money. See my edited question and answer below for the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is that a java.io.FileWriter doesn't use UTF-8 encoding by default. Instead use the following code to create the writer:

`def writer = new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream(outputFile),"UTF-8")`

Hat tip to http://www.malcolmhardie.com/weblogs/angus/2004/10/23/java-filewriter-xml-and-utf-8/ for the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Just use `replaceAll`:

```
yourHtmlFiles.each { f ->
 text = f.text
 text.replaceAll('&#8217;', "'");
 // save text
}
```

Answer (score 0):

While I agree that the character shouldn't cause any issues, here's a solution for very large files:

```
def replaceSingleQuoteCharacterInFile(def input) {
    if(input instanceof String) {
        input = new File(input)
    }
    File out = File.createTempFile("temp_xml", ".xml")
    out.withPrintWriter('UTF-8') { writer ->
        input.eachLine('UTF-8') { line ->
            writer.println line.replace('&#8217;', "'");
        }
    }
    out.renameTo(input)
}

def input = new File('/path/to/input.xml')
replaceSingleQuoteCharacterInFile(input)

println input.text
```

This will stream the file line-by-line, replacing the problematic character as it goes.  It also streams the output to a temp file, then replaces the original at the end, to prevent corrupting the input file during processing.

Note also the use of `replace` instead of `replaceAll` — there's no reason to use a `regex` for a simple static string replacement.

Comment: Also, you can easily make this a closure instead and pass it to `each` to iterate over a list of files, or Groovy's `eachFileRecurse` to process all files in a given directory.